# $\lVert f_{1}+\cdots+f_{m}\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}^{p}\le \frac{2-p}{1-p}\sum_{j=1}^{m}\lVert f_{j}\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}^{p}$

Tags: proof-verification, weak-lp-spaces

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measure space. Then for each $p$ between $0$ and $1$,we have 
$$\lVert f_{1}+\cdots+f_{m}\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}^{p}\le \frac{2-p}{1-p}\sum_{j=1}^{m}\lVert f_{j}\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}^{p}$$

Then we denote the distribution function as $\omega_{|f|}(\alpha)=\mu\bigg(\{x\in X:|f(x)|>\alpha\}\bigg)$

Here is my details to this proof (I edited):

First of all, if there were any one $\lVert f_{j}\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}\,\,$ is infinity,then our conclusion holds easily.

So we may assume each $\lVert f_{j}\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}<\infty$

For each $\alpha>0$,we observe that the following,

\begin{align}
&\alpha\mu\bigg(\{x\,:|f_{1}(x)+\cdots+f_{m}(x)|>\alpha\,,\max_{1\le j\le m}|f_{j}(x)|\le\alpha \}\bigg)\\
&=\int_{\{x\,:|f_{1}(x)+\cdots+f_{m}(x)|>\alpha\,,\,\max_{j}|f_{j}(x)|\le\alpha \}}\alpha&\,d\mu(x)\\
&\le\int_{\{x\,:|f_{1}(x)+\cdots+f_{m}(x)|>\alpha\,,\,\max_{j}|f_{j}(x)|\le\alpha \}}|f_{1}(x)+\dots+f_{m}(x)|&\,d\mu(x)\\
&\le\int_{\{x\,:|f_{1}(x)+\cdots+f_{m}(x)|>\alpha\,,\,\max_{j}|f_{j}(x)|\le\alpha \}}|f_{1}(x)|+\dots+|f_{m}(x)|&\,d\mu(x)\\
&\color{red}\le\int_{\,{\{x\in X\, :\,\max_{j}|f_{j}(x)|\le\alpha\}}} |f_{1}(x)|+\cdots+|f_{m}(x)|\,\,d\mu(x)\\
&\color{red}=\sum_{j=1}^{m}\int_{\{x\in X\, : \,\max_{j}|f_{j}(x)|\le\alpha\}} |f_{j}(x)|\,\,d\mu(x)\\
&\le \sum_{j=1}^{m}\int_{\{x\, : \,|f_{j}(x)|\le\alpha\}}|f_{j}(x)|\,d\mu(x)\\
&\leq\sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{\alpha^{1-p}}{1-p}\lVert f_{j}\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}^{p}\\
\end{align}

Then we yields a consequence that for each $\alpha>0$,

$$\alpha^p\mu\bigg(\{x\in X :|f_{1}(x)+\cdots+f_{m}(x)|>\alpha\,,\max_{1\le j\le m}|f_{j}(x)|\le\alpha \}\bigg)
\le\sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{1}{1-p}\lVert f_{j}\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}^{p}$$

Therefore we combine the previous result that for each $\alpha>0$,one has
\begin{align}
&\alpha^p\mu\bigg(\{x\in X :|f_{1}(x)+\cdots+f_{m}(x)|>\alpha\,\}\bigg)\\
&\le\alpha^p\mu\bigg(\{x\in X :|f_{1}(x)+\cdots+f_{m}(x)|>\alpha\,,\max_{1\le j\le m}|f_{j}(x)|\le\alpha \}\bigg)+\alpha^{p}\omega_{\max_{j}|f_{j}|}(\alpha)\\
&\le \sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{1}{1-p}\lVert f_{j}\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}^{p}+\alpha^{p}\omega_{\max_{j}|f_{j}|}(\alpha)\\
&\le  \sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{1}{1-p}\lVert f_{j}\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}^{p}\,\,+\bigg\lVert \max_{1\le j\le m}|f_{j}|\bigg\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}^{p}\\
&\le\sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{1}{1-p}\lVert f_{j}\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}^{p}\,\,+\sum_{j=1}^{m}\lVert f_{j}\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}^{p}\\
&=\bigg(1+\frac{1}{1-p}\bigg)\sum_{j=1}^{m}\lVert f_{j}\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}^{p}\\
&=\frac{2-p}{1-p}\sum_{j=1}^{m}\lVert f_{j}\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}^{p}
\end{align}

To the end of our proof when we take sup for every $\alpha>0$ at left hand side.

Well,if you have the time,please check this for validity,or just ignore it that it's okay . Any suggestion and valuable advice would be greatest appreciated.A lot of thanks for patient reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that 
\begin{align*}
\int_{|f_{1}+\cdots+f_{m}|>\alpha,\max|f_{j}|\leq\alpha}|f_{1}|+\cdots+|f_{m}|d\mu\leq\sum_{i=1}^{m}\int_{|f_{i}|>\alpha/m,\max|f_{j}|\leq\alpha}|f_{i}|d\mu
\end{align*}
does not hold. Rather, the correct one should be
\begin{align*}
\int_{|f_{1}+\cdots+f_{m}|>\alpha,\max|f_{j}|\leq\alpha}|f_{1}|+\cdots+|f_{m}|d\mu\leq\sum_{i=1}^{m}\int_{|f_{i}|>\alpha/m,\max|f_{j}|\leq\alpha}|f_{1}|+\cdots+|f_{m}|d\mu
\end{align*}

However, you are not far away to the goal. Here's the crucial step.
\begin{align*}
\alpha\mu(|f_{1}+\cdots+f_{m}|>\alpha,\max|f_{j}|\leq\alpha)&=\alpha\mu_{E}(|f_{1}+\cdots+f_{m}|>\alpha)\\
&\leq\int|f_{1}+\cdots+f_{m}|d\mu_{E}\\
&=\int_{E}|f_{1}+\cdots+f_{m}|d\mu\\
&=\int_{\max|f_{j}|\leq\alpha}|f_{1}+\cdots+f_{m}|d\mu\\
&\leq\sum_{i=1}^{m}\int_{\max|f_{j}|\leq\alpha}|f_{i}|d\mu\\
&\leq\sum_{i=1}^{m}\int_{|f_{i}|\leq\alpha}|f_{i}|d\mu\\
&\leq\sum_{i=1}^{m}\dfrac{\alpha^{1-p}}{1-p}\|f_{i}\|_{L^{p,\infty}}^{p}\\
&=\alpha^{1-p}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1-p}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\|f_{i}\|_{L^{p,\infty}}^{p},
\end{align*}
where $E=\{x\in X: \max|f_{j}(x)|\leq\alpha\}$, $\mu_{E}(A)=\mu(A)\chi_{E}$, rearranging we get
\begin{align*}
\alpha^{p}\mu(|f_{1}+\cdots+f_{m}|>\alpha,\max|f_{j}|\leq\alpha)\leq\dfrac{1}{1-p}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\|f_{i}\|_{L^{p,\infty}}^{p}.
\end{align*}